# How to move largest number of matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I need to move the largest number of randomly generated matrix to the right lower corner of matrix, but I don't know how. Can someone help.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, rows, columns;
    int **matrix;

    printf("write the number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("write the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);

    matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof *matrix);
    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
            printf("%5d", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you find the largest number in the matrix, then you swap it with `matrix[rows - 1][columns - 1]`.

Comment: Your question is a bit under-specified.  Do you need to swap the biggest number with the value at the bottom-right corner?  What should you do if there are several locations with the same largest value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following

```
int max = matrix[0][0];

for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
{
    for (j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
    {
        if ( max < matrix[i][j] ) max = matrix[i][j];
    }
}

matrix[rows-1][columns-1] = max;
```

If you need to exchange the right lower element of the matrix with the maximum element then the code can look like

```
int max_i = 0;
int max_j = 0;

for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
{
    for (j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
    {
        if ( matrix[max_i][max_j] < matrix[i][j] ) max_i = i, max_j = j;
    }
}

int tmp = matrix[rows-1][columns-1];
matrix[rows-1][columns-1] = matrix[max_i][max_j];
matrix[max_i][max_j] = tmp;
```

Comment: @Mangiux If it indeed helped then mark the answer as such.:)

Answer (score -2):

You can generate the matrix with the requested feature this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, rows, columns, largest, largestRow, largestColumn, swapValue;
    int **matrix;

    printf("write the number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("write the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);

    largest       = 0;
    largestRow    = 0;
    largestColumn = 0;
    matrix        = malloc(rows * sizeof *matrix);
    if (matrix == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
        if (matrix[i] == NULL)
        {
            int k;

            for (k = i - 1 ; k >= 0 ; k--)
                free(matrix[k]);
            free(matrix);

            return -1;
        }

        for (j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            if (matrix[i][j] > largest)
            {
                largestRow    = i;
                largestColumn = j;
                largest       = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    swapValue                         = matrix[rows - 1][columns - 1];
    matrix[rows - 1][columns - 1]     = largest;
    matrix[largestRow][largestColumn] = swapValue;

    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
            printf("%5d", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: About the only thing that could be said to be wrong is the initialization.  You don't initialize `largestRow` or `largestColumn`; that's a big problem.  Using `largest = 0.0;` is also dubious — it would be better to use either `matrix[0][0]` or `matrix[rows-1][columns-1]`, initializing the values of `largestRow` and `largestColumn` appropriately.

Comment: Wow, that is really a beginers mistake, i missed it. About largest, just see the expression for the random number generation, `0` is the smallest possible. Thank you.